# Rails Resque jobs cannot access database, i/o error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, resque

I have an error I cannot find any information on.  This is a Ruby on Rails stack (Ruby 1.9, Rails 3.2) and using sqlite3 database for development.  Resque and Redis are used for background jobs.  The rails web application starts up fine and can access and update the database.  I can login with sqlite browser and see records and run queries.  The issue is any Resque job cannot access database, and gets an I/O exception.  I can see the jobs on the resque web browser/queue and retry them but they still fail.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
Error
SQLite3::IOException: disk I/O error: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1
/Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step'
/Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `block in each'
/Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `loop'
/Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `each'
/Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:263:in `to_a'
/Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:263:in `block in exec_query'
/Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
```

Comment: FYI Also I can run rails console and do User.find queries just fine.  Seems within Resque job context there is no database connection or it has issues reading database file....

Comment: More info - I am on Mac 10.9 maveriks, installing mysql and using that resolved the issue.  Seems something to do with sqlite3 and resque

Comment: Nope, just used mysql

Comment: How are you running the worker?