# Rails 3.2 + Resque: testing in development causes SQLite3::IOException error in Resque dash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous, sqlite, redis

This question is related to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129160/rails-resque-jobs-cannot-access-database-i-o-error) from a few months ago.

I am following the [Railscast for Resque](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) to get it setup in my app for background job handling. I started by running `brew install redis`, then bundled the gem, then created `resque.rake` in `lib/tasks` with the following content:

```
require "resque/tasks"
task "resque:setup" => :environment
```

Then I created a directory called `resque_workers` and added the following worker class:

```
# new_job_worker.rb
class NewJobMailer
  @queue = :new_jobs

  def self.perform(id)
    sm = WorkerMailer.job_posted(id)
  end
end
```

In `JobsController#create` I added the following code:

```
Resque.enqueue(NewJobMailer, @job.id) # send emails in the background
```

In my terminal I have the redis server running, and I ran the `rake resque:work QUEUE='*'` command in one of my tabs per the Railscast instructions.

I've restarted my server and tried creating a job several times. Nothing breaks during app initialization. But in my Resque dashboard I can see that every job is failing with the following error:

```
SQLite3::IOException: disk I/O error: SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1
```

The trace leads back to my `WorkerMailer` class, which looks like this:

```
  def job_posted(job_id)
    @job = Job.find(job_id)  # this is the line that causes the error
    @category = @job.category
    subject = "New job #{@job} posted: #{@category}"
    msg = mail(subject: subject,
              to: ENV['EMAIL_WORKER_TO_ADDRESS'],
            from: ENV['EMAIL_NEWJOB_FROM_ADDRESS'],
             tag: 'worker job posted')
    msg.deliver
  end
```

The error is happening at `Job.find(job_id)`. For some reason it seems as though the Resque queue doesn't have access to my models, but I thought adding `task "resque:setup" => :environment` in `resque.rake` was supposed to account for that. At the same time, since the db call is technically not in the Resque worker, I'm not sure that I'm identifying the problem correctly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does that happen with MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: the development db is sqlite3

Comment: Try changing it to Postgres or MySQL and see if the problem persists. SQLite is notirious for its problems with concurrent access.